# Why is Travis-CI build failing?

Tags: ruby, rake, travis-ci

My build of [the4dpatrick/possible-email on Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/the4dpatrick/possible-email/jobs/32727448) is failing and I'm unsure why. It seems to be related to the `.travis.yml` file I have and Rake.

`.travis.yml`

```
language: ruby
cache: bundler
rvm:
  - 2.1.0
  - 2.0.0
  - 1.9.3
```

`Rakefile`

```
#!/usr/bin/env rake

require 'bundler/gem_tasks'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

desc "Run all specs"
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
  t.rspec_opts = ['--color', '--format', 'nested']
  t.pattern = 'spec/**/*_spec.rb'
  t.verbose = false
end

task :default => :spec
```

The [build logs from Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/the4dpatrick/possible-email/jobs/32727448)

Comment: Do the specs pass on our development machine?

Answer (score 0):

The `--format nested` option [in your `:spec` rake task](https://github.com/the4dpatrick/possible-email/blob/10d2ee13e00a3ca345a4a6f49419855add9d326d/Rakefile#L8) is invalid:

> /home/travis/build/the4dpatrick/possible-email/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:167:in `find_formatter': Formatter 'nested' unknown - maybe you meant 'documentation' or 'progress'?. (ArgumentError)

I suggest you to use `--format documentation` instead (see [other options](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/command-line/format-option)).

By the way, in order to make the option more readable, I would write:

```
desc "Run all specs"
  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
  t.rspec_opts = ['--color', '--format documentation']
  t.pattern = 'spec/**/*_spec.rb'
  t.verbose = false
end
```

Instead of:

```
desc "Run all specs"
  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
  t.rspec_opts = ['--color', '--format', 'documentation']
  t.pattern = 'spec/**/*_spec.rb'
  t.verbose = false
end
```

But both do work.